# Inspecting Tensorflow graph

Tags: tensorflow, graph, bazel

I was testing the command to inspect a custom built tensorflow graph.

The command I used is the one found in [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md#inspecting-graphs)

```
bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph --in_graph=/home/WarMachineRox/test_frozen_graph.pb
```

But it returns an error saying:

```
ERROR: Unrecognized option: --in_graph=/home/WarMachineRox/test_frozen_graph.pb
```

If I use in_graph option without '--', it returns:

```
ERROR: no such package 'tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms': BUILD file not found on package path
```

Is there anyway to inspect tensorflow graph input node without using this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph --in_graph=/home/WarMachineRox/test_frozen_graph.pb
```

should be two separate commands:

```
$ bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph
INFO: Analysed target //tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph (0 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.372s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action

$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph
2018-05-29 12:37:51.343760: E tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph_main.cc:313] in_graph graph can't be empty.
usage: bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph
Flags:
        --in_graph=""                           string  input graph file name
        --print_structure=false                 bool    whether to print the network connections of the graph
```

Comment: The second command returns an error: 
bash: bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_grap: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you running the command at the top level of the project directory?

Comment: I cloned tensorflow repository and ran the command on the top of the tensorflow folder. And there is bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph/ folder is created after the first command.

Comment: The second command must be ./bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph not bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph.

Comment: That's interesting, you shouldn't need to prepend `./` to run a binary if it's in a subdirectory. Edited my answer with the results of my invocation.